# How can I trigger `browse-url-at-point` using C-c C-o on URLs within programs?

Tags: web-browser, url

<kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-o</kbd> nicely opens the URL under the point in Emacs org-mode.

`goto-address-mode` can likewise be added as a minor mode to a program's major mode,

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook #'goto-address-mode)
```

That works perfectly—with the mouse. Clicking on the URL with the mouse opens the URL. (I am uninterested in using Emacs's internal browser as it is unwieldy, but luckily the link opens in an external browser.)

This is contrary to the spirit of Emacs. I'd rather do everything from the keyboard and seldom touch the mouse.

How can I trigger `browse-url-at-point` using <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-o</kbd> on URLs?

If I write

```
(global-set-key "\C-c\C-o" 'browse-url-at-point)
```

then this will trigger opening a URL regardless of whether the point is over a URL, which makes it seem like a hack.

Comment: FYI: `(add-hook 'python-mode-hook (lambda () (goto-address-mode)))` is the same as just `(add-hook 'python-mode-hook #'goto-address-mode)`.

Comment: The question isn't clear to me. 1. The title says "within programs" - what does that mean? 2. You say "using the default external browser, not within Emacs", but you say "at point". What do you mean? Is this about using `browse-url-at-point` **in Emacs** or using it (somehow) outside Emacs? 3. "isn't quite right" isn't clear. `browse-url-at-point` does try to open whatever is at point, but if there's no URL at point it raises an error. 4. Why mention `goto-address-mode` - seems unrelated.

Comment: @Drew Edited. Is this better?

Comment: Yes, thanks, but title is still not clear ("within programs"?). But you still don't say why `browse-url-at-point` tries to open non-URLs at point. It's code shows that it uses `browse-url-url-at-point` to test whether there's a URL at point. I think you need to give an example of a non-URL at point that `browse-url-at-point` mis-recognizes as a URL. Also: you can follow what `browse-url-url-at-point` does, step by step, by first doing `M-x debug-on-entry browse-url-url-at-point`. Finally, use `emacs -Q` (no init file), to be sure the problem isn't introduced by your init file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd> will open a URL, and only a URL.

Remembering distinct key mappings for the same operation in different modes is not ideal, but this is at least a starter.

Comment: "You"? You are the OP. Please say what `C-c RET` does that's different, and how it's "what you want", as opposed to what `browse-url-at-point` does.

Comment: @Drew Oddly, I keep referring to this answer (my answer), as I tend to type C-c C-o (as I do in org-mode) to open URLs from source code files. But returning here yet one more time I'm puzzled at your indignation. The standard on all SE sites is to target questions and answers to people who are in a hurry. Almost no one in the audience at large notices, let alone cares, that the person who asked and the person who answered are the same. They just want to know. For this reason self-answers addressing the question in the third person are as frequent as those addressing oneself, and the former ..

Comment: @Drew make much more sense for someone who's here in a hurry to find a quick answer and move on.